# navigate through javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date, object, navigation

do you know a way to "navigate" through the date object without writing an own extension?? eg. you have:

```
var x = new Date();
```

And then you want to click a button and go a month forward or backwards to get the next/previopus month automatically (with automatically year-change?..Is that possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a datepicker control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you just need to look at [the methods on the `Date()` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

This code will advance the date by one month and it will roll properly to the next year when needed:

```
var x = new Date();
x.setMonth(x.getMonth() + 1);
```

You can do similar things for the other properties.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qBRgF/
​

Answer (score 1):

You could increment or decrement days as utilizing this:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
   this.setDate(this.getDate()+days);
}
```

http://javascript.about.com/library/bladddays.htm

Months and years would be similar.

But if you're actually seeking a datepicker, use this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/